# Get in front of everyone to stop Ctrl-V (paste) operation to intercept and change clipboard contents

Tags: c#, clipboard, copy-paste, paste

I am trying to stop the normal Paste operation of clipboard, while I am processing and updating the clipboard contents.

I have written an application in c#, to implement a stack of global Copy Paste operations (currently for text format only). The copy operation is intercepted well by WM_CLIPBOARDUPDATED event and I push the content of clipboard in a stack.

The main problem comes when my keyboard hook detects the paste operation initiated by Ctrl-V, when I want to pop the stack back to the Clipboard, but while my function is completed, the paste operation by the system is completed.

To illustrate with an example, if I have copied 5 text strings and the stack is properly populated. I open a word document and press Ctrl-V (paste) operation. While my application is processing and about to change the contents of clipboard by popping from my stack. The paste operation already gets completed by something else in parallel to my function.

I have used time delay, lock, and unregistering the keyboard listener, but nothing worked.

I want to make my application be the first in the chain to get the Ctrl-V and then change the contents of the clipboard so that other applications and processes only get what I paste on the clipboard.

The code for Paste operation Intercept is as follows

```
        private int KbHookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
{
    if (nCode >= 0)
    {
        var hookStruct = (KbLLHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KbLLHookStruct));

        // Quick and dirty check. You may need to check if this is correct. See GetKeyState for more info.
        bool ctrlDown = GetKeyState(VK_LCONTROL) != 0 || GetKeyState(VK_RCONTROL) != 0;

        if (ctrlDown && hookStruct.vkCode == 0x56) // Ctrl+V
        {
            if (clipBoardStack.Count > 0)
            {
                lock (this)
                {
                    localChange = true;
                    RemoveClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);     // Remove our window from the clipboard's format listener list.
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                    Clipboard.SetText(clipBoardStack.Pop());
                    AddClipboardFormatListener(this.Handle);
                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(200);
                }

            }

        }
    }

    // Pass to other keyboard handlers. Makes the Ctrl+V pass through.
    return CallNextHookEx(_hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to intercept drag'n'drop and menus/customizable keyboard shortcuts :)

Answer (score 1):

You may register HotKey (Ctrl-V) with the system, so that the system can send control to the HotKey handler in your application. There you can update the Clipboard.

Since registering the HotKey will make system to notify only your application, therefore you will have control on what you do with the ClipBoard. Later on you will have to send the Ctrl-V combination to the target (intended) application. This will simulate as if the paste command has been issued by the user for the target application.

The downside of this is that you will have to know which application was in focus to send the key combination to later on.

Comment: I have tried the hot key solution, but then I get the control and no one else seems to know if there was a Paste operation required.